# Base64Encoder cannot be resolved

Tags: java

This is my Java code in a JSP file. I am getting

> Base64Encoder cannot be resolved.

Why is it so? I have to add something related to `Base64Encoder`. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.io.OutputStream,java.net.HttpURLConnection,java.net.URL,java.util.Collection,org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException,org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParams,org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpParams,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthPolicy,org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope,org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod,org.w3c.dom.*,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
String a_Url = request.getParameter( "url" ) ;

URL url = new URL (a_Url);
String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("test:test");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in   = 
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

%>
```

Comment: @BalusC, you edited the solution also in my code. or just the questions.. As I am still getting that erorr..

Comment: I did not edit the solution in your code. This makes no sense. I just fixed the formatting, the usage of English and removed irrelevant tags. Click the blue time link after "edited" below the question to see the diff.

Comment: @BalusC, I am still getting the error after importing com.oreilly.servlet. And I am working in eclipse. So what should I import now.

Comment: I have not posted any answer and I am also not interested in posting an answer on this question. All I did was just cleaning up your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you are using a class that does not exist in a jar you have included in the web application. Can you try the following? Make adjustments if necessary, I am just looking at the documentation for commons and typing this out --

1. Go to http://commons.apache.org/codec/index.html and read through the information there
2. Now go to http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi and download the zip file
3. Extract out the jar file and copy it to the lib directory of your web application
4. Replace the line
   [String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("test:test");]

with

```
String encoding = new String(
 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
    (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("test:test"))
  );
```

Answer (score 13):

I suspect you're not using a standalone JRE instead of the one included in the JDK.

1. Right click your project and click "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path"
2. Under "Libraries",  click on the existing JRE and then click "Remove"
3. Click "Add Library" -> "JRE System Library" -> "Finish"

The class should now resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to do an import or specify the fully qualified class name for Base64Encoder

Comment: You seem to be using the class Base64Encoder -- do you know what the package name of the class is? Try this -- go to the "lib" directory of your project and search through the jar files to see if you see a class named Base64Encoder. If it is there find its class and reference it. If it is not there, you are probably missing a jar file in the lib directory. To search through the jar files in lib directory, go through each one and do a 'jar tvf ' on it to see the classes contained within it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an inclusion of the namespace here for Base64Encoder.  Try adding 'com.oreilly.servlet' to your import.

Comment: thanks for replying back. I added that import, but on that import I am getting `The import com.oreilly cannot be resolved` and I am working in eclipse..

Comment: Raihan, I had assumed that you had already gotten that jar.  Try downloading it from http://www.servlets.com/cos/

Answer (score 0):

"Window"   ->   "Preferences"   ->  "Java" ->  "Installed JREs"
change  :
jre installation path

It should work.
[image]