# How to write encoded text to a file using Java?

Tags: java

How to write encoded text to a file using java/jsp with FileWriter?

```
FileWriter testfilewriter = new FileWriter(testfile, true);
testfilewriter.write(testtext);

testtext:- is text
testfile:- is String (Encoded)
```

What I m trying to do is encoding testfile with Base64 and storing it in file. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: the writing is exactly the same as writing any other text

Comment: you need to think about the encoding not writing

Comment: sun packages have Base64Encoder, but i recommend using commons-codec.

Comment: I tried commons-codec's Base64Encoder, but I m unable to store it in file via code

Comment: @Andy please show us the code you have tried so that you could get some specific help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is not plain text, you can't use FileWriter. What you need is [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Encode your text as Base64:

```
byte[] encodedText = Base64.encodeBase64( testtext.getBytes("UTF-8") );
```

and write to file:

```
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(testfile)) {
    stream.write(encodedText);
}
```

or if you don't want to lose existing data, write in append mode by setting `append` boolean to true:

```
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(testfile, true)) {
    stream.write(encodedText);
}
```

Comment: I m getting StandardCharsets and UTF_8 cannot be resolved to a variable error here.. getBytes(StandardCharsets,UTF_8) also I m getting Base64 not resolved error

Comment: Base64 was newly introduced in Java 8, as several Base64 implementations existed in parallel. Standardcharsets is a class since java 7, but not on Androids, that gives Charset constants for those Charsets that are delivered with every JRE. You can use  "UTF-8" instead. Here probably apache or another Base64 is meant.

Comment: That's because you didn't import either modules. Check here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526883/base64encoder-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can do the encoding yourself and then write to the file as suggested by @Alper OR if you want to create a stream which does encoding/decoding to while writing and reading from file , apache commons codec library will come in handy see [Base64OutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) and [Base64InputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html)

Interestingly Java 8 has a similar API [Base64.Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html). Checkout the [wrap method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Approach to be followed depends on the algorithm you are using and writing the encoded file is same as writing the file in java

IMHO, if you are trying to do it using **jsp** , Kindly go with servlets .As jsp are not meant for business layers rather do servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give the code, as it is pretty easy if you try it. I'll share the best way to do it as a psuedo code. Here are steps to write your encoded text.

1. Open input file in read mode & output file in append mode.
2. If input file isn't huge (it can fit in memory) then read whole file at once, otherwise read line-by-line.
3. Encode the text retrieved from file using [Base64Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html)
4. Write in the output file in **append** mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `FileWriter` directly for this task.

You asked how you can do it, but you didn't give any information about which JDK and library you use, so here are a few solutions with the standard tools.

If you're using **Java 8**:

```
String testFile = "";
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
    Base64.getEncoder().wrap(
        java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(
            Paths.get(testFile),
            StandardOpenOption.APPEND)),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    ) {
  writer.write("text to be encoded in Base64");
}
```

If you're using **Java 7 with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)**:

```
String testFile = "";
CharSink sink = BaseEncoding.base64()
    .encodingSink(
        com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink(
            new File(testFile),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
            FileWriteMode.APPEND))
    .asCharSink(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
try (Writer writer = sink.openStream()) {
  writer.write("text to be encoded in Base64");
}
```

If you're using **Java 6 with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)**:

```
String testFile = "";
CharSink sink = BaseEncoding.base64()
    .encodingSink(
        com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink(
            new File(testFile),
            Charsets.UTF_8,
            FileWriteMode.APPEND))
    .asCharSink(Charsets.UTF_8);
Closer closer = Closer.create();
try {
  Writer writer = closer.register(sink.openStream());
  writer.write("text to be encoded in Base64");
} catch (Throwable e) { // must catch Throwable
  throw closer.rethrow(e);
} finally {
  closer.close();
}
```

I don't have much knowledge about other libraries so I won't pretend I do and add another helper.

Comment: Looks Promising. Actually its a jsp page I'm working on and the text to be encoded is taken from textbox from a web page.